# Upload a track to Apple Music (API)

Tags: api, apple-music, apple-musickit

Is there a way to upload the track from my computer to Apple Music?

Apple provided an API, but I only found the following request from it:

`POST https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/playlists/{id}/tracks`

As I understand, this request can add track to the playlist that already uploaded to Apple Music.